# I'm unable to spot the errors in this script?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following script

```
#./bin/bash

#Check Error Script

echo "Try to find out some errors!!!"

# Search for the words which can be matched by regex [^a]*ce
echo "The regex [^a]*ce can match the string(s):" > Result
# And append matched strings to file "Result"
cat <<START | grep '[^a]*ce$' > Result
lance
ace
brace
decide
piece
-END

# The append the output of command simple.sh to file "Result"
.simple.sh>>Result

echo "Congratulations! You have corrected all the errors!"
```

And I'm trying to get it to say

> Try to find out some errors!!! Congratulations! You have corrected all
> the errors!

but it keeps showing

> ```
>  Try to find out some errors!!! ./checkError.sh: line 21: warning: here-document at line 10
>  delimited by end-of-file (wanted `START')
> ```

Comment: Check your code at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/* Check Error Script */` comment is interpreted as globbing (do `ls -ld /*` and you'll see), matching `/1` which it tries to execute.

Use `#` for comments in bash.

You also have a *here*-document that you start with `START` but you try to end it with `-END`. Use `END` in both places.

Also, `cat <<START | grep '[^a]*ce$' > Result` should most probably be `cat <<END | grep '[^a]*ce$' >> Result`. Note the `>>` to append before `Result`.

Something like this:

```sh
#./bin/bash

# Check Error Script

echo "Try to find out some errors!!!"

# Search for the words which can be matched by regex [^a]*ce
echo "The regex [^a]*ce can match the string(s):" > Result
# And append matched strings to file "Result"
cat <<END | grep '[^a]*ce$' >> Result
lance
ace
brace
decide
piece
END

# The append the output of command simple.sh to file "Result"
.simple.sh>>Result

echo "Congratulations! You have corrected all the errors!"
```

Note: This requires the script `.simple.sh` to be in your `PATH`. The comment above it suggests that the script's name is `simple.sh` and not `.simple.sh`, so if `.simple.sh` doesn't exist, I'd try `simple.sh` or `./simple.sh`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but  I'm still getting an error in line 10, but I can't spot it

Comment: @kashmafia Yes, this answer solves the problem you asked about. You may accept the answer and post another question. Try to limit your questions to specific problems.  I updated the answer though.